# How to retrieve an embedded image source for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, .net-4.0, imagesource

I have a program which has loaded in a few 'plugins' using MEF. I have the dll file for each 'plugin' and access to the interface used for the MEF export and import.

The interface contains a title and an image (system.drawing) for each 'plugin' and I would like to display these in a list in my main program. I do not possess the image files themselves. They are embedded resources in the dlls.

My problem is that the WPF control I am using only has an ImageSource property and therefore I cannot bind the image that was loaded in from each 'plugin' dll.

It seems what I need to do is extract a relative path to the embedded image file from the image itself. I'm not sure it's possible.

**I would like to show my embedded resource images in the WPF main window**

I am using C# and .Net 4.0 in VS2015

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have control of the plugin DLLs? If so, you may want to look at [Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately not :( but thank you very much for your quick reply. I've been hunting in the direction of GetManifestResourceStream but so far no joy.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for how to convert System.Drawing.Image to ImageSource. There are several ways to do that.

Comment: That's what I've been doing for the past 2 days!

Comment: They are all embedded resources. I had another go with @Clemens suggestion to try imagesource and it worked! Clemens would you please phrase that as an answer and I'll accept it!